# Error when setting property in prepareForSegue:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting the following error when trying to set a string in a public property in prepare for segue. Any idea why?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setQuestionObjectId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa713562b40'
```

The code is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"postSegue"]) {
    CommentsViewControllerNew *commentsVC = (CommentsViewControllerNew *)[segue destinationViewController];
    commentsVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    PFObject * question=[self.brightenArray objectAtIndex:self.indexPathOfClickedpost.row];
    commentsVC.questionObjectId=question.objectId;
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.Array objectAtIndex:self.indexPathOfClickedpost.row]);
//        commentsVC.question = question;
```

Comment: Please show your `CommentsViewControllerNew` code so we can see your @property for question.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have already gathered, this is caused because you are sending a `setQuestionObjectId:` message to a class that doesn't recognise that message. E.g. if you send a `reloadData` (from `UITableView`) message to an `NSString` then you will get a similar exception. This is because `NSString` doesn't implement (have a method) called `reloadData`.

This error often happens in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method because you are typecasting a `UIViewController` to a custom subclass (in this case `CommentsViewControllerNew`). The typecasting happens on this line:

```
CommentsViewControllerNew *commentsVC = (CommentsViewControllerNew *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

You are essentially telling the compiler: Yes I know that you think this is a `UIViewController` but it's actually a `CommentsViewControllerNew`. The crash comes because, in this case the compiler is right, it ***is*** a `UIViewController` and `UIViewController` doesn't have a method or property name called `questionObjectID`

After that long explanation... The fix is to go to your Interface Builder, select the relevant view controller and set its class as `CommentsViewControllerNew`.

NOTE: If you don't understand, or are unfamiliar with any of what I'm talking about, I suggest you do some reading or do a few tutorials. There are loads of good ones on YouTube.